# javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Method X is exposed as WebMethod, but there is no corresponding wsdl operation

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I'm integrating with a third party web service (Adyen) using JAX-WS RI. I have downloaded a copy of their wsdl and have used `jaxws:wsdl2java` in my build to generate the web service implementation source code.  At runtime, when I attempt to setup a port by calling the getPort() method of my auto-generated Payment service class, I get the following exception claiming that there is a method exposed, but it is not present in the wsdl portType element:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Method adjustAuthorisation is exposed as WebMethod, but there is no corresponding wsdl operation with name {http://payment.services.adyen.com}adjustAuthorisation in the wsdl:portType{http://payment.services.adyen.com}PaymentPortType
```

But, it is present in the portType element. Here's the relevant snipped of the wsdl:

```xml
<wsdl:portType name="PaymentPortType">
  <wsdl:operation name="adjustAuthorisation">
    <wsdl:input name="adjustAuthorisationRequest" message="tns:adjustAuthorisationRequest" />
    <wsdl:output name="adjustAuthorisationResponse" message="tns:adjustAuthorisationResponse" />
      <wsdl:fault name="ServiceException" message="tns:ServiceException" />
  </wsdl:operation>
  ...
</wsdl:portType>
```

The full wsdl can be seen here: https://pal-live.adyen.com/pal/servlet/Payment/v30?wsdl

The wsdl is included in the target jar with classpath /wsdl/Payment.wsdl. I am loading it at runtime using this code in a config class:

```java
URL wsdl = getClass().getResource(wsdlLocation);
onlineService = new Payment(wsdl, new QName(serviceUrl, serviceName));
```

Where `serviceUrl = "http://payment.services.adyen.com"` and `serviceName = "Payment"` which matches the wsdl.

Finally, here's the code snippet where I attempt to open the port and ultimately get the exception:

```java
ClassLoader oldClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
try
{
  port = config.getOnlineService().getPaymentHttpPort(); // exception thrown here
}
finally
{
  Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(oldClassLoader);
}
```

Any ideas why it seems to be misreading the wsdl? Another potentially important piece of info is that I recently updated the wsdl, previously my app used version 12 of Adyen's API with the corresponding wsdl, now I am upgrading to version 30. The application worked fine with the same code previously.

Comment: After reading your question it is not clear which web services framework you are using. On the one hand you indicate JAXWS RI, but ```wsdl2java``` is a CXF task. Please could you clarify this point? Could you include the ```wsdl2java``` task description from your ```pom.xml``` in the question?

Comment: Any progress on this? Please, can you expand your question as indicated in my previous comment? I think it will be of great help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace for the `javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException` shows what's happening under the hood when constructing a new `Payment` service using the code generated from the wsdl:

```
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:265) ~[jaxws-rt.jar:2.2.10]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:246) ~[jaxws-rt.jar:2.2.10]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:209) ~[jaxws-rt.jar:2.2.10]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:178) ~[jaxws-rt.jar:2.2.10]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:363) ~[jaxws-rt.jar:2.2.10]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:321) ~[jaxws-rt.jar:2.2.10]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:230) ~[jaxws-rt.jar:2.2.10]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:211) ~[jaxws-rt.jar:2.2.10]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:207) ~[jaxws-rt.jar:2.2.10]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:114) ~[jaxws-rt.jar:2.2.10]
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
    at com.amazon.adyen.payment.Payment.<init>(Payment.java:58) ~[?:?]
```

`RuntimeWSDLParser.parse` calls `java.net.URL.openStream`, which calls `sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream` since in this case, the wsdl in part of the jar.

When calling `getInputStream` on a `URLConnection`, the default behavior is to check the cache. This can be disabled for a given connection by opening a connection to the resource, setting `useCaches` to `false`, and then opening the input stream. However, the code which opens the stream to the resource is auto-generated in this case, and modifying the generated classes wouldn't be a good solution for future changes.

`URLConnection` also has a `setDefaultUseCaches` method, which will set the behavior for the current connection and all future connections. See the documentation in the `URLConnection` source code: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/net/URLConnection.java#l245

I was able to force the wsdl to be loaded from the jar by setting this default flag, and then reverting it after loading the resource.

The working code is below which loads the resource from the jar if there is an error fetching it from cache:

```java
URL wsdl = getClass().getResource(wsdlLocation);

URLConnection connection = wsdl.openConnection();
try {
    onlineService = new Payment(wsdl, new QName(serviceUrl, serviceName));
} catch (WebServiceException wsException) {
    // if wsdl resources in the jar have changed, an exception will be thrown due to
    // loading the old version from cache. Attempt to load without using the cache.
    LOG.warn("Failure initializing service. Trying again without using URLConnection caching. Caught exception: ", wsException);
    connection.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
    onlineService = new Payment(wsdl, new QName(serviceUrl, serviceName));
} finally {
    connection.setDefaultUseCaches(true);
}
```

If you are able to load the input stream directly, you could do the following without touching the default caching behavior that could affect other connections:

```java
URL wsdl = getClass().getResource(wsdlLocation);
URLConnection connection = wsdl.openConnection();
connection.setUseCaches(false);
InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
```

Answer (score 5):

You have a mismatch between the wsdl file that you are using to generate classes and the wsdl file that you are loading at runtime.

- the classes were generated using the newer version, since the error mentions WebMethod `adjustAuthorisation`.
- the wsdl loaded at runtime is an older version and it does not contain the `adjustAuthorization` method.

Notice the difference between `v30` and `v12`:
[image]

Comment: that was my takeaway too from the error message, but I'm not sure how to debug this or fix it. The v30 wsdl is built into the jar, then referenced by classpath in the config class. I have checked the deployed jar by unzipping it and verified the v30 wsdl is included as intended.

Comment: Maybe there is another version of that resource somewhere on the classpath. Can you log the wsdl URL to make sure that the correct wsdl from the correct jar is picked up? (i.e. this value: `URL wsdl = getClass().getResource(wsdlLocation);`)

Comment: I have deployed a change to log this line, the result is `jar:file:/[project root]/lib/[project name]-1.0.jar!/wsdl/Payment.wsdl`. I'm not sure this totally eliminates the possibility of a cached value though since it's not an absolute file reference.

Comment: Try to log this `new java.util.Scanner(config.getOnlineService().getWSDLDocumentLocation().openStream(), "UTF-8").findWithinHorizon(java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("<wsdlsoap:address [^>]*>"), 1000000)` just before you create the port. It will read the wsdl that the service is using and look for a specific line. The desired output is `<wsdlsoap:address location="https://pal-live.adyen.com/pal/servlet/Payment/v30"/>`

Comment: I found it was due to `URLConnection` caching...by opening a connection to the wsdl URL and calling `connection.setDefaultUseCaches(false)` the wsdl was forced to be loaded from disk rather than the cache.

Comment: In my case this error was generated because I forgot to refresh the webservice client in one of my java libraries, so its local wsdl was outdated. Thanks :)